# How to remove specific object from array in reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a reducer for the user module and need to delete the single object from the array of users, but same time, I need to keep those all old records

For example

Below is my dummy data for the initial state

```js
export const initialSettings = {
  timezone: '',
  category: '',
  users: [
    {
      userId: '1',
      name: 'ABC'
    },
    {
      userId: '2',
      name: 'ABCD'
    },
    {
      userId: '3',
      name: 'ABCDE'
    },
    {
      userId: '4',
      name: 'ABCDEF'
    },
  ]
};
```

Here in above const, I have array users which contain the list of users as a separate object

I am able to get the user details and trying to remove specific object into reducer like this

```js
switch (...) {
  case 'ADMIN_REMOVE_RX':
    const data = action.payload.data; 
    const userid = data && data.userid; 

    return {
      ...state,
      users: state.users.filter(item => 
        item.userid !== userid
      )
    };

  default:
    return state;
}
```

In the end, I'm able to get the output but it no longer working when I try to filter the user's array, correct me if something wrong with it

Comment: In your initialState userId value is string I.e., for eg '3' so change it to 3. Since you are using !== check it expects both operands to be in same type

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error part is

```
const userid = data && data.userid;
```

check the data type of **data.userid**, if **data.userid** is a string, then you won't get the as expected output, because of **!==** (strict comparison operator).

Answer (score 0):

Check the item property name, in the object is in camel case item.userId but in filter is in lowercase item.userid

```
state.users.filter(item => item.userId !== userid)
```